# Maven - Runnable JAR NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm creating a runnable JAR with maven and all works fine. With assembly i include my libs on external folder but when i run it my application start and at some point i get `NoClassDefFoundError` This class is `org.json.JSONException`.

I'm using [this](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j) library that require JSON classes. I've tried to clone the repository and build it because i have had to make some changes.

When i run my project from Eclipse all works fine, no error and application works. But, when i run it from JAR executable i got this error.

Looking in the repository i've noticed that this use json artifact, so i have included it in my `pom.xml` but without results....

All others library are loaded correctly.

This is the build phase of the pom.xml (i have omitted dependencies, if will be necessary i'll include too)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <!-- Make an executable jar, adjust classpath entries-->
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>it.mypkg.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <!--Resources will be placed under conf/-->
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>./conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <!--exclude the properties file from the archive-->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly/distribution-zip.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And this is the assembly (both configuration come from another stackoverflow thread):

```
<assembly>
    <id>dist</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <!--Include runtime dependencies-->
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get the generated application jar-->
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get application resources-->
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <!--Get misc user files-->
            <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>README*</include>
                <include>LICENSE*</include>
                <include>NOTICE*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>       
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

**EDIT**: I add dependecy list because i've noticed that when i remove json dependency in my `pom.xml` i got the same error. Json dependency is not needed for my project but is used in the link i've provided you above.

When i remove json project dont work in Eclipse
When i add json project works in Eclipse
With or without Json library, project dont works as runnable JAR (is missing that dependency - json)

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>  
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uses Castor for XML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
            <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Castor need this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fusesource</groupId>
            <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>parse</groupId>
            <artifactId>parse4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
         -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>   

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Dont think this is a duplicate of that thread... i've a problem just with one library, all others library works fine...

Comment: Without a full pom file and the commands you have used it's impossible to guest what's wrong..

Comment: edited with pom and assembly config

Comment: @Mistre83 I see you are using maven assembly plugin. which is also an beta version. Can you try the solution mentioned here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596779/how-to-make-jar-file-independent/37608076#37608076

Comment: First you should use uptodate versions of plugins and not extremely old versions of plugins (maven-assembly-plugin 2.6, maven-jar-plugin 2.6 or 3.0.0)..Furthermore what you need is a `jar-with-dependencies`. The configuration be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html